# define an harmonic oscillator function to use in odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm triying to write an ode to solve an harmonic oscillator problem and  I have this problem with my function harmonic to use in odeint command.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

k=4.0
m=1.0
B=0

def harmonic((x, y), t):
    return [y, -k * x / m + B / m * y]
```

Gives the error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-60-2d6b156227be>", line 1
    def harmonic((x, y), t):
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Someone can help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: You do not need parentheses around x,y. Remove them and it will work.

Comment: Can you show how `odeint` is called in your code? Or, the differential equation that defines the change in y w.r.t x and initial conidtion at `y=0`?

Comment: @BenT  Thanks! I have solved the problem

Comment: @amanb Thanks ! I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

k = 4.0
m = 1.0
B = 0

def harmonic(var, t=None):
    x, y = var[0], var[1] # var is assumed to be an array, usually numpy array
    return [y, -k * x / m + B / m * y]

result = odeint(harmonic, (0.2, 0), np.linspace(0, 1, 100))
plt.plot(result[:,0], result[:,1], 'r-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`(x, y)` represents a tuple. If you want to just use x,y as individual variables, simply use `x,y`. Your function will look like this:

```
def harmonic(x, y, t):
    return [y, -k * x / m + B / m * y]
```

Passing hypothetical values  for x,y & t to the harmonic function returns the list calculated by the code in the `return` statement of the function:

```
harmonic(2,3,5)
#Output:
[3, -8.0]
```

Comment: But this won't work with `odeint`.  `x` and `y` must be put into a single array of length 2.

Comment: That would require additional information like, y0 and how does y change with x. Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: Yes, that's right.  As @David Vivas said, *"... I have this problem with my function harmonic to use in odeint command"* (but the code that calls `odeint` is not shown).